# how to run two different spring boot instances?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a need to run two separate spring boot instances, the first instance is responsible for some code-generation, while the second is serves as an API.

Here is the process:
1. Run the generation spring boot app
2. After the generation is shutdown, run the API spring boot app

```java
// Api.java

@Log4j2
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Api {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Api.class, args);
    }
}

// Generator.java
@Log4j2
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Generator implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Generator.class, args);
        Api.run(args); // run the API instance
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // do generation here
    }
}
```

Exact error:
`Error creating bean with name 'nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication`

The error I'm currently getting is that there is already a spring boot instance, and hence can not call `Api.run(args)`.  I'd like to be able to run both of these one after another.  If there is a better way I'm all ears.  At the end of the day it needs to be a single runnable jar.  My main class is configured to point to the Generation, and theoretically it should generate the code then run the Api.

Comment: "The error I'm currently getting is that there is already a spring boot instance"  Show the **exact** error.

Comment: `Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication`

Comment: Edit your question with the details

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this to run 2 services - User Service and Project Service:

```
    SpringApplicationBuilder uws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(UserWebApplication.class)
            .properties("server.port=8081",
                    "server.contextPath=/UserService");
    uws.run();
    SpringApplicationBuilder pws = new SpringApplicationBuilder(ProjectWebApplication.class)
            .properties("server.port=8082",
                    "server.contextPath=/ProjectService");
    pws.run();
```

They use different ports and context paths.